Geometry Nodes - Minimum Volume Bounding Box
I am trying to understand how I can create a bounding box that occupies the minimum volume of a selected object. Using the bounding box node when an object has its rotation information returns the expected results (45, 0, 0) (Left), but how would I get this same result on an object with its rotation frozen (0, 0, 0) (Right)?
The geometry node below is just to visualize the example. :)


The simple answer is you cannot. The bounding box is the box spanning over the maximum extent of an object on all three axes of the local orientation. When you apply the rotation, this will be reset to global orientation. Now meshes can be very complex, how should Blender know when there are edges not aligned with the global axes that these are some which it should base the orientation of a bounding box on? If you would take a Convex Hull node, this would be closer to the mesh because it is independent of orientation, but of course it is something completely different than a Bounding Box.

I should have been a bit more specific. While I understand how the bounding box is functioning, and that it specifically could not get me the results I need, I'm trying to understand if geometry nodes has the support to replicate this effect independent of the transform rotation values of the object, and where a starting point to doing this might be. The reason I am looking to generate this as a box, and not a convex hull is to be able to turn this into UBX collision for exporting to Unreal. The following video is a good example. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTZ2Hbnu7Tc

Would it be possible to find the longest length of an object or volume, and create the shape starting from there?

I think you are looking for Principal Component Analysis.

Well, we all know geometry nodes are magic, so here we go.
This answer is an approximation, it gets better the bigger the rotation_steps.
Warning!
This procedure is SLOW! And it may crash your blender. Use with care! (Better used once and applied)
Up to 40 steps work in my PC. Pretty sure there are ways to optimize these nodes, but this is a first naive attempt. (Ultimate goal is to use instances instead of repeat zones, but this requires bigger brains).
One way to optimize, for instance, is to make bigger rotation steps first, find a sweet rotation and then make smaller rotation steps only in a smaller range.
Main nodes

The purpose is:

Rotate the geometry many times in Z, Y, and X
Calculate the bounding box and its volume for each rotation
If lower than the previous, store as min box and min volume

Rotation setups
Rotate the position of the geometry in each axis. (The geometry input/output is only necessary in the last rotation, but it was kept for inspection with a viewer node if needed)
Z

Y

X - This one outputs the final used geometry

Calculate Box Setup


Creates the box for the rotated geometries
Calculates the volume of the boxes
If volume lower than the previous stored minimum

Store new minimum
Unrotate the box and store it as minimum box (the unrotate matches the box with the current position of the object, but you could skip the unrotate if you need)



File
Warning: this file contains 3 geometries using around 30 steps, it might be slow to open.


exactly my idea :D https://i.imgur.com/MvxuCVc.png  https://i.imgur.com/mDNtTJE.png But it is problematic, because the mesh may fall into a local minimum, so you may want to check multiple combinations first and "gradient descent" for them...

Well, as it is now, the answer doesn't fall into a local minimum (it is a full brute force sweep)

Ohhh, so with given resolution you test all possible rotations? I instead rotate randomly and discard rotations that don't decrease volume.

Yeah... (hence it's slow) I'm thinking of making a recursive node. You add the nodes with maybe 10 steps, then add another modifier with the same nodes again, more 10 steps and so on. You can reach a 1000 steps resolution within 30 iterations.

Interesting! I will have to explore this more. Do you think it would be possible to convert the mesh to a convex hull (for simplicity), scatter points across the mesh surface, and then compare those into two groups of points that are furthest from each other, and then find a center point in each group and connect them? I wonder if you could then use the the normal of the line to align the box to... I am not sure how you would find the radius to scale the other two axis though. I'll try and get an image to demonstrate this idea better.

"There must exist two neighbouring faces of the smallest-volume enclosing box which both contain an edge of the convex hull of the point set. This criterion is satisfied by a single convex hull edge collinear with an edge of the box, or by two distinct hull edges lying in adjacent box faces"

this is just some amateur idea, that came to my mind image: https://i.imgur.com/hd1Bh4b.gif file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/oPayQrDR Getting the median of the mesh and the longest face distance to it, then rotating the object to this vector.

another test, this could maybe help to eliminate some rotations for first answered method https://i.imgur.com/3cLN1nI.gif

Going to explore this option more! Thanks for the input everyone!

Other direction - principal components decomposition to build largest diagonals of the bounding box.

Since that is a statistical analysis, it would fail many times for meshes with outlying vertices.

I do not see why this would...
